# Goodbye PF&MSO!

Tags: discussion

Goodbye, Stack Overflow! It's been fun collecting 11,758 Internet points and helping start the overflow site, but I'll be leaving as part of the Monica Cellio backlash.

Comment: [Backstory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/145951).

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I’m sorry to see you (and so many other SE users that I respect) go. It is certainly making me question my future here.

Comment: @Fennec - I'm sorry to see you leave. These are interesting times, and I think there's still some good things going on here. I've been here nearly 10 years, and for now, will whether the storm. I appreciated your participation, and want you to know you're always welcome here.

Comment: Please see [An apology to our community, and next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps).

Comment: And see [Dear Stack Exchange: A Statement and a Letter from your Moderators](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators)

Comment: See also https://dearstackexchange.com

Comment: also why does my account still exist

Comment: Don't worry, it's gone. Account deletion is not instant. Also, the content won't be removed. Just the account associated with it.

Comment: "Who were you, user296?" https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Nothing is sacred anymore to please the 'agenda'...  trace the money and you will  find answers to ALL questions!

Comment: Which user was this?! Evidently with over 11,000 rep they were someone who participated a lot.

Comment: @Vicky they were quite active in the early days of the site, but hadn't done much recently

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam thanks for the info. I’m quite glad it’s not you!

Comment: @Vicky The name was in the post for some time before a CM deleted the member name. See my comment above, where I said goodbye.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer ahhhh, thanks!

Comment: @Vicky I'm not close to leaving the site or even just resigning as a mod at the moment, though I have very mixed feelings about the current situation (far too long to put in a comment!) and things seem to be going gradually downhill rather than getting better.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I'm glad it's not just me. I'm giving it a bit longer and then we'll see..... :-/

Comment: @Mr.deSilva - Re. money: hey man, this isn't tagged *reality check* ;)